# Acumatica Tax Category REST API

Tags: acumatica

I am creating an application which will sync Tax Category details from Magento to Acumatica. I am planning to use the REST API to update tax categories at acumatica but I am unable to find REST API to update TAX Categories at Acumatica. Please suggest a way to update Tax Category at Acumatica.

Comment: You can always create your own endpoint: https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=709351cc-566a-47b3-b153-3a9fdd690ce0

Comment: @Brendan I have created a custom endpoint, I have added two new attributes to tax class. How shall I update it?

Comment: Is this a general how to for working with the end points? the Training course should provide you with everything you need. Also if you look at help.acumatica.com you can search endpoint and find a lot of references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below to update the Tax category record in Acumatica.

Url:

```
/entity/Default/18.200.001/TaxCategory
```

Method: PUT

```
Request:
{
    "TaxCategoryID": {
        "value": "EXEMPT"
    },
    "Active": {
        "value": true
    },
    "Description": {
        "value": "Exempt Tax Category"
    },
    "ExcludeListedTaxes": {
        "value": true
    },
    "Details": [
        {         
            "TaxID": {
                "value": "MANUALID"
            },
            "TaxType": {
                "value": "Sales"
            },
            "Description": {
                "value": "Manual"
            },
            "CashDiscount": {
                "value": "Does Not Affect Taxable Amount"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Screenshot]